# contact form 7 "before_mail_send" stop from sending and show custom message instead

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I use the contact form 7 "before_send_mail" function to check a form field and if the value inside the field "password" matches the predefined password. If the value inside the field "password" equeals the valuable $definedPassword the form should execute normally but when the value is different i dont want to execute the form and show a custom message instead. Im glad for every help:

```
<?php 
    add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_login_stream_check' );

    function wpcf7_login_stream_check($WPCF7_ContactForm) {
        $definedPassword = "234";
        $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm :: get_current();
        $form_id = $wpcf7->id;
        
        if ($form_id === 105) {
            $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();  
            if ($submission) {
                $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
                $password = $posted_data['password'];
        
                if($password == $definedPassword ) {
                    /*  NORMAL BEHAVIOUR */
                } else {
                    /* PREVENT FORM FROM SENDING AND SHOW CUSTOM-MESSAGE */
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unless you need to run a sql query to determine a password is valid in the DB, id be tempted to approach this using JS instead of php. If you're determined to use php, you need to check if the form value equals your $definedpassword using ISSET

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using `before_send_mail` you would be best to use the form validation function.  If your field is a text field, and the password is static... This will work if you add to your functions.php.  If you're not using `[text* password]` you can adjust the tag type accordingly in the `add_filter`

Tested with Contact Form 7 5.2.2

```php
function cf7_check_password_field($result, $tags) {
    $definedPassword = "234";
    
    $tags = new WPCF7_FormTag( $tags );

    $name = $tags->name;
    
    // Check the tag name is password or exit
    if ($name !== 'password') return $result;
    // if the password isnt valid
    if ($_POST['password'] !== $definedPassword){
        // set your message here
        $result->invalidate( $tags, __( 'Password does not match.', 'text_domain' ));

    }
    return $result;
}

add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text', 'cf7_check_password_field', 20, 2); // text field
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'cf7_check_password_field', 20, 2); // Req. text field
```